# a picture and text in the same row, with the height of the image vertically aligen with the center of the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, tikz-node

I want to type the following in tikz:

[image]

The image is positioned to the left (let's say 10pt away) from the text. I want the image to be the height of the font (normal font of the document) and to be vertically aligned with the center of the text.

To produce the image I use the following:

```
\smash{\includegraphics[height=\ht\strutbox]{example-image}}
```

and what I have now to position the two is

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [outer sep=0pt] {\smash{\includegraphics[height=\ht\strutbox] (m1) {example-image}}};
\node [right=10pt of m1.center,anchor=south west,fill=green,outer sep=0pt] (m2) {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

for which I get the following:

[image]

i.e. the image baseline is in the same height of the text base line. But I want the image center to be in the same level as the text center.

I think that the answer is in the values passed to `right= of m1.___` and `anchor`.

But I tried multiple combinations of them and I can't get it right.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (m1) [outer sep=0pt] {\smash{\includegraphics[height=\ht\strutbox]{example-image}}};
\node [right=0pt of m1.base west,anchor=mid west,fill=green,outer sep=0pt] (m2) {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also `base right=… of …` which deals with the anchors automatically but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Why are you using `\smash`? That makes the left node have no height that's in relation to its content. Do you want the image span the height (and depth!) of the strutbox with the same baseline as the green node? The green node will not have the height (and depth) of a `\strutbox` because in this case it doesn't have a depth and it adds `inner ysep`s. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I found this `smash` command somewhere here in the website a while ago. If you have a better suggestion, you are more than welcome to write it down!

Comment: To calrify: I just want a small picture to be positioned to the left of the text, and want it to be vertically aligned with vertical span that the text takes (as I showed in the top most image). I am sorry but I don't know what depth is. There is height and width. What is depth?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel is there a way to tell the height of the image to be that of the text it is next to? I am thinking of typing something similar to this but just for `\section`s.

Comment: Everything in TeX has a height (vertical dimension above the baseline) and a depth (vertical dimension below the baseline). The `\strut(box)` just declares one specific height/depth but in your case `some text` doesn't cover that because it has no descenders and `\strut(box)` is even higher than S. If it just needs to `\strutbox`, that not a problem but if it needs to be dependent on the actual text, it isn't that straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a graphic that has the total height (meaning height *and* depth) of a `\strutbox`, I'll suggest using `\raisebox` and `totalheight`:

```
\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
  \includegraphics[totalheight=\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox]
    {<image>}
```

In a node with no `inner sep` this will also make the node only that height and width of the image which having the baseline of the node (i.e. all the base anchors) at the right position.

Then you can use the `base right`key to position the second node in relation to their baselines.

---

The height (`\ht`, `text height` in TikZ) is the vertical dimension of a box above a baseline, the depth (`\dp`, `text depth`) specifies the vertical dimension of a box below the baseline.

The `\strutbox` usually has a height `.7\baselineskip` and a depth of `.3\baselineskip`.

I've added a `\showStrut` that shows that strut with a thin line but doesn't interact with the actual height/depth of the line/box/node (via `\smash`). This also shows with the help lines that the image is aligned correctly … whatever the actual content of the node.

I haven't changed the `inner xsep` or `inner ysep` values of the right node which is why it will always have some padding around the text.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\showStrut{\smash{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{.1pt}{\baselineskip}}}
\newcommand\tikzImageAndText[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m1.base)]
\node[
  path only, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt](m1) {%
    \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
      \includegraphics[totalheight=\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox]
        {#1}}};
\node[
  base right=10pt of m1,
  fill=green, outer sep=+0pt] (m2) {\showStrut #2};
%%% Debug
  \tikzset{every path/.append style=help lines}
  \draw (m1.base east)  --  (m2.base west);
  \draw (m1.south east) --++(right:15pt);
  \draw (m1.north east) --++(right:15pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\tikzImageAndText{example-image}{Some text}
\tikzImageAndText{example-image}{\strut Some text}

\tikzImageAndText{example-image}{(g}
\tikzImageAndText{example-image}{.\strut}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Well done. And a very fine explanation.

Comment: This works fine for text of normal size. Can you devise a solution for the same size of image to sit in the same baseline with text of larger size e.g. `\large` or `\Huge`?

Comment: `\large \tikzImageAndText{example-image}{Some text}` should work. Or using something like `nodes={node font=\large}` as an option to the TikZ picture. It will get more complicated to have the left node pick up the dimensions of the right node before the right node got constructed. (Though, placing the right node first and the then left one second might be an appropriate solution.) If you want to use this in a section heading this will be dependent on how you implement this and what class you'll be using.

Comment: Making an image the height of a given strutbox is independent of TikZ, you'll just need `\raisebox` and `\includegraphics` where the proper font (size) is installed.